# How to read and write to/from file at a bit level precision in Java

Tags: java, file-io, bit-manipulation, bitset

I am little new to bit level reading and writing to/from file.

I want to read and write to file with precision at bit level. i.e. read exactly same number of bits in buffer as it is written.

Here is my attempt:

**1) Write to file method**

```
private static final int INT_BYTES = Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
public void writeToFile(FileChannel fc, BitSet bitSet, int intId ) throws IOException 
{
  //each bitSet has a intId, first two int bytes written will have intId and bitSet.length() and rest will have content of bitSet

  int byteLenOfBitSet=(int)Math.ceil((bitSet.length/8.0)); 

  ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteLenOfBitSet + 2*(INT_BYTES));
  bf.putInt(intId); //put the Id    
  bf.putInt(bitSet.length(); // put the bit length, it would be used during read
  bf.put(bitSet) //FIXME this is wrong, need to put bits , bf.put() put bytes               
  bf.flip();
  fc.write(bf);

}
```

**2) Read from file method**

```
   public Result readFromFile(FileChannel fc) throws IOException 
    {
      long currentPos = fc.position();
      ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2* INT_BYTES);

      if(fc.read(bf) < 0)return null;
      bf.rewind();
      int intId=bf.getInt();    //read first int as intId
      int bitLen = bf.getInt(); //read second int as bitLen to read further from file   
      int byteLen=(int)Math.ceil((bitLen/8.0));  //FIXME not so sure

      //move fc read position ahead by 2 INT_BYTES to read bitSet
      fc.position((currentPos + INT_BYTES * 2));        
      bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteLen);//FIXME, this is wrong, we need to somehow get bit not in bytelen , don't want unnecessarily read entire byte if there is less than 8 bit of info to read            

     if(fc.read(bf) < 0)return null;

     bf.rewind();
     BitSet readBitSet = new BitSet();

     //TODO, then read each bit from bf to a readBitSet
     // and return result with intId+readBitSet   

   }
```

In another set of methods, where I had to read and write just Integers (at byte level) I had got it working fine using logic similar to above. But, got stuck at bit level.

Please let me know if need more clarification.

It might be similar to [Read and write file bit by bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599200/read-and-write-file-bit-by-bit)
but that answer is for Perl, I am looking for implementation in Java

**EDIT**

**My concern:**

Since data are written to file this way

```
2 INT_BYTES then bitSet   example: 5 3       101
2 INT_BYTES then bitSet   example: 2 10 1010111101
```

I am concerned I might read second `2 INT_BYTES` while trying to read first `bitSet`, so my first result bitSet would be wrong. So, wondering how to ensure that bit level boundary is maintained. i.e. I want to read until first BitSet's length only when reading first bitSet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the smallest unit you can read using standard interfaces is a byte.  To deal with smaller you must buffer the byte data yourself and keep track of partial bytes.

Comment: Thanks, suppose BitSet written has length just 1, but I read entire byte. Won't my buffer will include that 1 bit and as well as 7 bits from next INT_BYTE? or there is way to extract just BitSet's 1 bit from reading entire Byte using some bit manipulation technique. Any code example will greatly help.

Comment: Like I said, you have to keep track of the partial bytes yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379283) includes a BitSet subclass that has a `toByteArray` method.  To write, you can get the `byte[]` array from that method and use `ByteBuffer.put(byte[])` ([ByteBuffer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)).  To read, you can use `get()` and then loop over the `byte[]` and rebuild the bitset.

(For reference: [FileChannel docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29))

EDIT in answer to your [question below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188166/how-to-read-and-write-to-from-file-at-a-bit-level-precision-in-java#comment35466247_23188221).

- I think you can get rid of `fc.position` since `fc.read` and `bf.getInt` both advance their current positions.
- According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373159/2877364), the parameter to `allocate` should be the number of bytes you want to read with a call to `fc.read`.  So `2*INT_BYTES` looks correct for the first `allocate` call.  The second `allocate` also looks OK; just don't call `fc.position`.
- For `byteLen`, try `byteLen=(bitLen >> 3) + ((bitLen&0x07)?1:0)`.  `bitLen>>3` divides by 8 (2^3) with truncation.  So 1..7 bits have zero, 8..15 have one, ... .  If the number of bits is not a multiple of 8, you thus need one more byte.  `((bitLen&0x07)?1:0)` is 1 in that situation and 0 otherwise.

Bear in mind that the bits will be padded at the end if you don't have a multiple of 8.  E.g., reading 12 bits will take two full bytes from the stream.

Comment: +1, thanks, i will try that. Can you please also confirm that my `fc.position(..)` and `bf.allocate(..)` is correct while reading. I won't somehow tip on first two `INT_BYTES` or last two `INT_BYTES` while trying to read the `bitSet` from file.